# How to retrieve CSS style object by CSS class name?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get all properties of a css class associated with an element?
e.g.

```
.hightligh {
   font-weight: bold;
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding-top:10px;
}
```

Lets say the css class "hightlight" is assigned to div element

```
<div class='highlight'></div>
```

Now using JavaScript, I need to iterate through all style properties of css class "highlight" associated with the div element.
Basically, I want to treat it as a JavaScript object whose properties can be accessed using iterator or for loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to know this then just inspect the element in firebug.

Comment: If you're looking for values set through a stylesheet, there's no quick fix (that I know of) to get those styles. However, here's a snippet that fetches the computed style (Firebug uses something like this) of a specific element. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html#link7

Answer (score 0):

it's relatively easy to build something like that with the normal DOM functionality. Here is an example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
var retnode = [];
var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b');
var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
var classes = elem[i].className;
if (myclass.test(classes)) retnode.push(elem[i]);
}
return retnode;
};
```

However, rather than rolling your own, it's a better use of your time probably to examine jQuery selectors. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is a good place to start. Here is [the exact answer](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to your specific query with jQuery.

Comment: there is no need to suggest a full blown library for something as simplistic as this.

Comment: @user551841 that's why I gave the nod toward jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and chrome have

```
document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")
```

For IE you'll have to iterate through each ID and check if the class is what you want to use

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length;i++)
            if(elems[i].className == nameRequired)
                return elems[i]
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` is supported in IE8. It has different functionality, but it can be used (jQuery uses it) to fetch items by class name.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Chir wants to iterate through the style properties of the div corresponding to the class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as useful as you might think, you have to keep in mind inheritance and order, and styles applied directly to elements. But you can return all the css rules by their selectors, in IE7+ and most of the other browsers since then:

```
function getRules(rx){
    var A= [], tem, R= this.cssRules || this.rules, L= R.length;
    if(typeof rx== 'string') rx= new RegExp('\\b'+rx+'(,|$)', 'i');
    while(L){
        tem= R[--L] || '';
        if(tem.selectorText && rx.test(tem.selectorText)){
            A[A.length]= tem.style.cssText || '';
        }
    }
    return A;
}
function getAllRules(sel){
    var A= [], S= document.styleSheets, L= S.length, tem;
    while(L){
        tem= getRules.call(S[--L], sel);
        while(tem.length){
            A[A.length]= tem.shift();
        }
    }
    A= A.join(';').split(/;+\s*/);
    return A;
}



getAllRules('body')// element selector
getAllRules('#p_opts')//id selector
getAllRules('.emhooCss')// class selector
getAllRules('#ul_tree h4 span')// descendent selector
getAllRules(/\b(body|div|p)\b/i)//rx for multiple selectors
```

to make an object involves splitting up the pieces of the array

```
function Cssruler(sel){
    var R= getAllRules(sel), L= R.length, tem;
    while(L){
        tem= R[L--] || '';
        tem= tem.split(/\s*\:\s*/);
        if(tem.length== 2) this[tem[0]]= tem[1];
    }
    this.selector= sel;
}
```

var R= new Cssruler('body')

```
R contains an object like this:

{
    background: 'none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(250, 250, 250)',
    background-color: 'black',
    background-image: 'url("starynte.gif")',
    color: 'black',
    left: '0pt',
    margin: '0pt',
    padding-top: '2.5em',
    right: '0pt',
    selector: 'body',
    width: 'auto'
}
```